# Populate default value only for hh:mm:ss part of datetime-local

Tags: jquery, datetime

Something like this works:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="myDate" value="2020-01-02T11:42:13">
```

BUt not this one:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="myDate" value="yyyy-mm-ddT11:42:13">
```

I want to have date to be selectable from calendar and time to have default value. Any suggestion without using third party library like moment, etc. I can use JQuery though.

Reference url: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime-local_value2

Comment: I don't think that's possible.. Are you allowing user to pick time from any sort of UI? or user can change time value?

Comment: No, User can pick only date from UI and time has to be manually typed. You can check the reference url:   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime-local_value2

Comment: Then it is quite not possible even with `jquery`. One suggestion would be to use separate `time` type `input` specific to `time` since, however the user has to enter the value..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao- Thanks for suggestion, i am looking for somekind of event that can trigger method to populate time when date is selected. Hrishi- I don't want user to have burden on selecting time everytime he selects a date. Don't want to do that at database layer, want to do that at client side only, any other way you can suggest ?

Comment: I think I can do that using onchange="PopulateDefaultMethod()" and write javascript to take selected date + default time value.

Answer (score 0):

According to specification https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.value , this won't be possible. You can use separate date and time input fields and set values like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date = new Date()
  
  var hours = String(date.getHours()).length==1?"0"+date.getHours():date.getHours()
  var minutes = String(date.getMinutes()).length==1?"0"+date.getMinutes():date.getMinutes()
  var seconds = String(date.getSeconds()).length==1?"0"+date.getSeconds():date.getSeconds()
  var time =  hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds
   
  $("#myTime").val(time)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="myDate" value="">

<input type="time" id="myTime" value="">
```

Comment: This way, date and time both will be populated by default, I wanted to have only time as default. And empty value for date.

Comment: I understand your intention now - i don't think this is going to be possible , based on the specs here - https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.value .  You can split it in 2 fields, see my updated answer